# Importing a .pfx or .p12 file to a remote certificate store is not supported

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, pfx, mmc, server-core

I try to use MMC with SnapIn Certificates(Remote Computer) to import a p12 certificate into the Personal Certificate Store of a remote Windows 2008 Server Core computer.

Certificate Import Wizard tells me:
'Importing a .pfx or .p12 file to a remote certificate store is not supported'

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that I can do everything with *certutil* and *winhttpcertcfg* like this:

1) add .p12 to Personal key store

```
 certutil -p P@ssword -importpfx cert.p12
```

2) add .cer certificate as trusted publisher

```
 certutil -addstore TrustedPublisher cert.cer
```

3) check which users have access to certificate

```
 winhttpcertcfg -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -s certificate.name -l
```

3) grant access to certificate

```
 winhttpcertcfg -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -s certificate.name -g -a user@domain.com
```